# How to set validation message on dropdown list?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, .net-core

Here's the problem. I have a [Range] attribute above the `SalesCenterId` property of my `ViewModel`. On my view side I have dropdown list with a default option "---Select---" and some Sales Centers with different Id-s. For example, if I set the Range between 0 and 1, then when selecting a sales center with Id = 2, my custom error message works. But when i select the default option "---Select---" (id = 0 , range between 1 and 1000) then the default error message is displayed: "The value '---Select---' is not valid for `SalesCenterId`." Why is this? I've checked through debugging and saw that when choosing "---Select---" Id = 0.

I'm using MVC core 2.2

ViewModel:

```
public class OrderViewModel
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*The Last Name field is required.")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*The First Name field is required.")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*The Middle Name field is required.")]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*The Pin field is required.")]
        public string Pin { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*The Phone field is required.")]
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*The Email field is required.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "*The Serial Number field is required.")]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 1000, ErrorMessage="jgsjfdngi")]
        public int SalesCenterId { get; set; }

        [Range(1, 999, ErrorMessage = "jgsjfdngi")]
        public int OrderTimeId { get; set; }

        [JsonIgnore]
        [IgnoreDataMember]
        public SalesCenter SalesCenter { get; set; }

        public List<CartItem> Cart { get; set; }

        public OrderTime OrderTime { get; set; }

        public decimal TotalPrice { get; set; }
    }
```

Validation message span:

```
<p><span asp-validation-for="SalesCenterId" class="error"></span></p>
```

Select list:

```
<td>
<select id="SCID" asp-for="SalesCenterId" asp-items="@ViewBag.SalesCenterId" class="input" style="width:200px; height:30px; padding:1.5%">
<option>---@Localizer["Select"]---</option>
</select><br />
</td>
```

I expect the output to be "jgsjfdngi", but the actual output is "The value '---Select---' is not valid for SalesCenterId."

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) might be what you need

Answer (score 0):

Have you used `ModelState.IsValid` in your controller??
Try this

```
if (ModelState.IsValid)  
 {  
  // your code  
  return View();  
 }  
 return View();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I'm new to programming and may be don't get your point properly but as far as i understand, i think ModelState.IsValid is just for displaying some error. But my problem is more about displaying custom error. I already get error message displayed, but i need to customize it.